# Impala ODBC connection using SIMBA

Tags: hadoop, odbc, impala

I referred Impala ODBC connection provided by Simba/CDH and installed it. I'm using CDH5.3 and Impala 2.1.0.

in odbc.ini, i tried port 21050,21000 but not able to connect to Impala. Later I used port 10000 and able to connect. Not sure if it this port really runs query in Impala as when I run 'select count(*) from emp'  at isql -v impala_simba, it takes lot time as compare to running same query in from Impala-shell.
I doubt if the configuration really uses Impala or Hive ?
I also tried with the CDH provided Impala ODBC connection but that also has same issue.

Can you please advise what's correct Impala port i should mention in .odbc.ini so that it runs query in Impala ?

here's configurations.

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
impala_simba=Simba Impala ODBC Driver
[impala_simba]
# Description: DSN Description.
# This key is not necessary and is only to give a description of the data source.
Description=Simba Impala ODBC Driver (64-bit) DSN
# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to.
Driver=/opt/simba/impalaodbc/lib/64/libsimbaimpalaodbc64.so
# The DriverUnicodeEncoding setting is only used for SimbaDM
# When set to 1, SimbaDM runs in UTF-16 mode.
# When set to 2, SimbaDM runs in UTF-8 mode.
DriverUnicodeEncoding=1
# Values for HOST, PORT, KrbFQDN, and KrbServiceName should be set here.
# They can also be specified on the connection string.
HOST=10.74.163.109
PORT=10000
Database=default
# The authentication mechanism.
# 0 - no authentication.
# 1 - Kerberos authentication
# 2 - Username authentication.
# 3 - Username/password authentication.
# 4 - Username/password authentication with SSL.
AuthMech=2
# Kerberos related settings.
#KrbFQDN=
#KrbRealm=
#KrbServiceName=
# Username/password authentication with SSL settings.
UID=abhi
#PWD
CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1
TrustedCerts=/opt/simba/impalaodbc/lib/64/cacerts.pem
# Specify the proxy user ID to use.
#DelegationUID=
# General settings
TSaslTransportBufSize=1000
RowsFetchedPerBlock=1000
SocketTimeout=0
StringColumnLength=32767
UseNativeQuery=0
```

Comment: Issue resolved. Make AuthMech=0 and remove UID as remote client will connect to Impala without authentication.

Comment: just to clarify, are you saying that with authentication you can connect but the performance is slow, without authentication performance is fast?